# What is the fastest way to take all possible 3 rows in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I have a matrix **mx3**. I would extract all possible groups composed by 3 row-vector. For example, from

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];
```

I would obtain:

```
v1 = [1 2 3], v2 = [4 5 6], v3 = [7 8 9]

v1 = [1 2 3], v2 = [4 5 6], v3 = [10 11 12]

v1 = [1 2 3], v2 = [7 8 9], v3 = [10 11 12]

v2 = [4 5 6], v2 = [7 8 9], v3 = [10 11 12]
```

Furthermore I need to repeat the same process on all possible matrices **(m-1)x3**. So in the example at the beginning I have to delete the first row, then the second one, then the third one and finally the fourth one.

That's not all! I need to repeat the process on all possible matrices **(m-i)x3** unitl ***(m-i)>=3*** (in the example I stop with **i=1**).

I know there is the function *nchoosek* and it can do this work, but first of all it is slow and above all it requires to create a matrix with all the possible combinations (and it's non tolerable when the starting matrix has many rows since there are too many combinations).

Can you help me about this odd question?

EDIT: I need to verify a property of the matrix. And to do this I have to compare 3 rows at time.
Let call the matrix **A** with dimension **mx3**. If I find only one triplet doesn't satisfy the property, I move to a subset of **A**, with dimensions **(m-1)x3**. Note that in this case I have **m** possible subsets! So if the property is not satisfied for one subset, I need to work with the other ones.
If no **m** matrices of dimension **(m-1)x3** fulfill my condition, I need to consider matrices of dimension **(m-2)x3**. Here start problems, because there are many combinations to check.

And so on until I find the maximum **(m-i)x3** matrix where each triplet satisfies the property.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to do the calculations only once for your mx3 matrix and get rid of wrong values for the smaller ones.

Comment: If you think it takes a long time to *generate* all of those combinations, just wait until you try to *process* all of those combinations.

Comment: @BillBokeey Great idea. But in practice?

Comment: @Alessandro : will post an answer tomorrow

Comment: I will need some precisions in order to post the most efficient answer. What are your planning to do with your datas afterwards? Do you really need ALL these set of three vectors stored or would it be okay for you if i have a way to fetch them dynamically via indexing?

Comment: More important : what is the maximum size of your Matrix A?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please ask me whatever you need.

Comment: Will M happen to be bigger than 62?

Comment: Unfortunately, it will. And I know it is a really big problem.

Comment: Can you tell me the condition your triplets have to satisfy in order to pass the test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92252/discussion-between-alessandro-and-billbokeey).

Comment: Going from m=3 to maximum possible value of m is faster. So that you can discard trivial violators earlier.

Comment: I don't think so. If the input matrix has many rows, there is a very large number of subsets 3x3